# AWS AppSync Graphql Subsciprtion - Trigger subscription if input to subscription is within a list from Mutation

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-appsync

In AWS AppSync, I have the following GraphQL schema.

```
type Mutation{
  myMutation(id:String!): MyResponse
}

type Subscription{
  mySubscription(ids:String):MyResponse @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["myMutation"])
}

type MyResponse{
  ids:[String]
}
```

My goal is to be able to trigger the subscription 'mySubscription' whenever the mutation returns MyResponse such that the list 'ids' ***contains*** the single id inputed into 'mySubscription'.

So, for example, in React-Native, I'd do the following:

```
import * as subscriptions from '../graphql/subscriptions.js'

const mySub = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(subscriptions.mySubscription,{ids:'1'})).subscribe({
  next: (response) => {

   // DO SOMETHING WITH RESPONSE

  },
  error: (err) => {

  // CATCH ERROR

  }
})
```

I'd want this subscription to trigger whenever 'myMutation' generated a response such as

```
data:{
  myMutation:{
   ids:['1','2']
  }
}
```

or where ids is any other list, as long as it contains '1' (the id inputed into the subscription).

The reason for this is that I have events that need to trigger notifications for clients based on who was attached to the mutation in the first place, where the actual list of people attached to the mutation is dynamic. It'd be nice to be able to says 'subscribe to any event where the list of people contains my name', type of thing.

My only work around was to trigger a notification mutation for each of the people individually involved, but this requires more calls to my server and seems way more difficult than I feel like it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Subscriptions only work with data input into your mutation, not with the outcome of the mutation result. Are you trying to send a subscription message based on the result of the mutation response? You may want to have the client or your backend data source / pipeline resolver send a message to the subscription stream (via another mutation) if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Aaron_H it may be an issue with Appsync, but Subscriptions CAN work on mutation result see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#subscription-filters the payload is the result of the mutation.